# Programmatically create Gatsby pages from Contentful data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, contentful, gatsby

I am looking for help with GatsbyJS and Contentful. The docs aren't quite giving me enough info.

I am looking to programmatically create pages based on contentful data. In this case, the data type is a retail "Store" with a gatsby page at /retail_store_name

The index.js for each store is basically a couple of react components with props passed in e.g. shop name and google place ID.

1. Add data to contentful. Here is my example data model:

   ```
   {
       "name": "Store"
       "displayField": "shopName",
       "fields": [
           {
               "id": "shopName",
               "name": "Shop Name",
               "type": "Symbol",
               "localized": false,
               "required": true,
               "validations": [
                   {
                   "unique": true
                   }
               ],
               "disabled": false,
               "omitted": false
               },
               {
               "id": "placeId",
               "name": "Place ID",
               "type": "Symbol",
               "localized": false,
               "required": true,
               "validations": [
                   {
                   "unique": true
                   }
               ],
               "disabled": false,
               "omitted": false
           }
   }
   ```
2. I've added the contentful site data to gatsby-config.js

   ```
   // In gatsby-config.js
   plugins: [
       {
           resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
           options: {
           spaceId: `your_space_id`,
           accessToken: `your_access_token`
           },
       },
   ];
   ```
3. Query contentful - I'm not sure where this should happen. I've got a template file that would be the model for each store webpage created from contentful data.

As mentioned this is just some components with props passed in. Example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class IndexPage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        placeId: "",
        shopName: "",
    };
}
render (){
    return (
        <ComponentExampleOne shopName={this.state.shopName} />
        <ComponentExampleTwo placeId={this.state.placeId} />
    );
}
```

I'm really not sure how to go about this. The end goal is auto publishing for non-tech users, who post new stores in Contentful to be updated on the production site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create pages dynamically at build time and to do that you need to add some logic to the `gatsby-node.js` file. Here is a simple snippet.

```
const path = require('path')

exports.createPages = ({graphql, boundActionCreators}) => {
  const {createPage} = boundActionCreators
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const storeTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/store.js')
    resolve(
      graphql(`
        {
          allContentfulStore (limit:100) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                name
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `).then((result) => {
        if (result.errors) {
          reject(result.errors)
        }
        result.data.allContentfulStore.edges.forEach((edge) => {
          createPage ({
            path: edge.node.slug,
            component: storeTemplate,
            context: {
              slug: edge.node.slug
            }
          })
        })
        return
      })
    )
  })
}
```

the `createPages` that was exported is a Gatsby Node API function you can find the complete list in the docs [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/).

For the query `allContentfulStore` it's called like that because your contentType name is `store` the gatsby query will be allContentful{ContentTypeName}.

Finally, I created a youtube video series explaining how you can build a Gatsby website with Contentful. You can find it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek4o40w1tH4&list=PL8KiuH6vpACV-F7jXribe4YveGBhBeG9A)

I hope this answer your question.
Cheers,
Khaled

Comment: Getting `GraphQLError: Syntax Error GraphQL request (16:6) Expected Name, found <EOF>` when running this. Any reason as to why?

Comment: try deleting `.cache` and `public` folder also you can check the query in the GrapiQL server that gatsby spawns with your dev build it should be `localhost:port/___grapql` Maybe the ContentType is named differently not store

Comment: @KhaledGarbaya , your YouTube video is truly awesome! Thank you for your help. It is greatly appreciated.