# Programmatically create Gatsby pages from API data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

This is a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255528/programmatically-create-gatsby-pages-from-contentful-data).

I'm looking for help programmatically creating pages using createPage or createPages and am having trouble - the docs give an example for creating pages from markdown files but not much explanation.

I am using a plugin in plugins\characters\gatsby-node.js to add data from the Rick & Morty API to the GraphQL data layer. My plugin is at the bottom of the question in case it is relevant.

The plugin does add the data successfully as I can see the data in http://localhost:8000/___graphql, and I have successfully managed to use the data in (static) pages.

**Where I am lost is that I would like to be able to create a page for each individual character, using the url `characters/<characterIdHere>` for each of the pages. I am aware that I need to add some logic to my (main or plugins version of....?) `gatsby-node.js` file, but this is the part I am stuck on. I do not know what I need to put into the `gatsby-node.js` file.** The examples I can find all use json or markdown files and I would like to use data that I have pulled in (from an API) to gatsby's data layer. I have obviously researched this for a few hours and played around with it before asking, but not had any luck.

The component on the pages I would like to create should look something like this:

```
const CharactersViewSingle = ({ character}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>{character.name && character.name}</title>
      </Helmet>
      <NavBar />
      <CharactersViewBox character={character} width={300} height={520} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

The above code is taken from what the component returned when I was using create-react-app.

The graphQL query (which obviously reflects the structure of the data I would like to use) I use  to get the data on other (static) pages  looks like this:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query CharactersQuery {
    allCharacters(limit: 5) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          status
          gender
          image
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Plugin code:

```
const axios = require("axios")

exports.sourceNodes = async ({
  actions,
  createNodeId,
  createContentDigest,
}) => {
  const { createNode } = actions

  const integerList = (start, length) =>
    Array.from({ length: length }, (v, k) => k + start)

  const rickMortyURL = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${integerList(
    1,
    493
  )}`

  const rickMorty = await axios.get(rickMortyURL)
  const query = await axios.get(rickMortyURL)
  rickMorty.data.forEach(character => {
    const nodeContent = JSON.stringify(character)
    const nodeMeta = {
      id: character.id.toString(),
      //id: createNodeId(`char-data-${character.id}`),
      parent: null,
      children: [],
      internal: {
        type: `Characters`,
        content: nodeContent,
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(character),
      },
    }
    const node = Object.assign({}, character, nodeMeta)
    createNode(node)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gatsby's `createPages` API is what you might be looking for.

I used it to create multiple pages like blog1, blog2, blog3 etc...
In the same way, you can create multiple pages for your characters.

Since you mentioned you have a graphql call to get your characters using

```
const pages = await graphql(`
 query CharactersQuery {
    allCharacters(limit: 5) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          status
          gender
          image
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)
```

The above graphql call returns results in `pages.data.allCharacters.edges`

Now you can iterate them using foreach and use createPage to create the pages.

Below is complete mock code you might need to add in your `gatsby-node.js` file

```
    const path = require('path');

    exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
      const { createPage } = actions
      const templateOfYourCharacterPage = path.resolve(`src/templates/exampleTemplateFile.jsx`)

    const pages = await graphql(`
     query CharactersQuery {
        allCharacters(limit: 5) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
              status
              gender
              image
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `)

      let characters = pages.data.allCharacters.edges;

      characters.forEach(edge => {
        createPage({
          path: `/${edge.node.id}`,
          component: templateOfYourCharacterPage,
          context: {id: edge.node.uid, name: edge.node.name } // This is to pass data as props to your component.
        })
      })

    }
```